# Which acceleration equations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

Which equation gives the most accurate answer?

$$a=g \sin⁡ α-μg \cos⁡ α\\
a=s/t/t\\
a=2s/t^2 -(2v_0)/t$$

Because i get three different answers. 
The scenario is a box sliding down on an inclined plane. Both are made of wood. I Used a sensor to take the time, and messured the lenght of the plane and the angle of it.

Comment: Can you show how you came to those three equations? And did you also measure if the acceleration is constant? - if not it is not possible to get a single number for $a$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of acceleration, $a = \frac{dv}{dt}$ is always correct, and any other equations of acceleration are derived from it, depending on the conditions. To use this equation, you need to have a basic understanding of calculus.

For example: condition: constant acceleration. This means $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is constant. This means that $v = at + constant$ or (upon using the boundary condition: $t=0, v=u$,

$v = u + at$

This derived equation is only valid for this condition (i.e. acceleration is constant). Any attempt to use a derived equation outside of the conditions from which it was derived will result in errors.